# Chrome extension : Load HTML pages conditionally with user details from popup.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need a help! I am newbie in chrome extension and I am get stuck with my below case so anyone can look into this case?

We need to load HTML pages with user details by conditionally in default popup box from popup.js file. I have added below code in popup.js. When user is logged-in extension then call "main.html" file (we are storing user details in chrome.storage by using chrome.storage.sync.set() APIs and get that user details by following code in popup.js file).
and when user logout then show "login.html" in default popup

```
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["user"], function(items) {
   if (!items.user){
    window.location.href = "login.html";
   } 
   else {
    $("#usernameId").text('Welcome '+items.user.username);
    $("#totCreditId").text(items.user.tot_credit);
    $("#leftCreditId").text(items.user.left_credit);
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
 });
```

It working fine but user details are not reflected (username, total credit, left credit etc..) in main.html page, Can you please correct me what I am doing wrong in it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assigning/changing `window.location.href` causes the page to _reload_, so all changes in DOM you make are lost.

Comment: @hindmost, thanks for your reply!, Should I use chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup:"main.html"}) instead of window.location.href ?

Comment: I'd suggest using conditional rendering within the same HTML page instead.

Comment: @hindmost thank again:) It would be great help if you can provide an example of it?

Comment: See [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-rich-chrome-extension-quickly-with-create-react-app-and-redux-d9b64cf64832) for example (plug!)